# unwanted refresh page bootstrap/font-face

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

hi there ia have a html code like this

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>


<body>
<?php 
$_SESSION["iphrase"] = $_SESSION["iphrase"] +1;
echo $_SESSION["iphrase"];?>
</body>

</html>
```

and in css:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Droid-Naskh';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url('../fonts/DroidNaskh-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/DroidNaskh-Regular.woff') format('woff');
}

body {
  font-family: 'Droid-Naskh';}
```

for each refresh page I expect this result:
1,2,3,4,5,6...

But it print: 
1,3,5,7

the problem is for this code:

```
 body {
      font-family: 'Droid-Naskh';}
```

why and how fixed it?

Comment: who says the problem is for this code? CSS and PHP code has nothing to do with each other.

Comment: I check my code. I sure the problem is  'font-family: `Droid-Naskh';`.

Comment: Why is that @elize, that font doesn't  have even numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
$_SESSION["iphrase"] = (isset($_SESSION["iphrase"])) ? $_SESSION["iphrase"] + 1 : $_SESSION["iphrase"];

echo $_SESSION["iphrase"];
```

I'm considering you've written `session_start();` at the top, somewhere in the code before incrementing session value.